# Dynamic table size with java servlet

Tags: java, html, database, servlets, jdbc

I have a little problem when I'd like to view selected data in a table in browser. I made it for one  table (with 3 columns) but I'd like to make it for all tables, with a different number of columns, how to give a dynamical size to this table in my browser?

```
pw.println("<table border=1>");
             while(rs.next())
             {
                 pw.println("<tr><td>"+rs.getInt(1)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(2)+"</td>"+
                                 "<td>"+rs.getString(3)+"</td></tr>");
             }
         pw.println("</table>");
         pw.close();
```

I tried to do like this:

```
           while(rs.next())
             {
                 for(int i=1; i<n; i++){pw.println("<tr><td>"+rs.getString(i)+"</td></tr>");}
             }
```

where n is number of columns(I'll count it), but the result is just first row in vertical order:

It's supposed to be |1 |first_n | last_n | but it's :

- 1
- first_n
- List item

Comment: You should not print HTML directly from Servlet. Instead, store the data to display in the table inside request attribute, forward to the desired JSP that contains the data, and in the JSP provide the necessary styles (CSS) to maintain the size of your HTML table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have the  tags inside the column output.

You need to put  outside the for loop containing the columns:

```
   while (rs.next()) {
     pw.println("<tr>");
     for (int i=1; i<n; i++) { pw.println("<td> ...
     pw.println("</tr>");
   }
```